# Best way to break up a function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, shopping-cart

im currently learning javascript and trying to create a shopping cart system and to get it to work ive created abit of a mess so i was just wondering what would be the best way to break the code up below to a more readable set of functions thanks.

```
function updateModal() {
let cartProducts = sessionStorage.getItem("foodInCart");
cartProducts = JSON.parse(cartProducts);
let totalPriceValue = 0
totalPriceValue = sessionStorage.getItem("totalPrice")
let cartModalProduct = document.querySelector('.product');
let cartModalPrice = document.querySelector('.price');
let cartModalQuantity = document.querySelector('.quantity');
let cartModalTotalPrice = document.querySelector('.total-price')
if (cartProducts !== null) {
    cartModalProduct.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(cartProducts).map(food => {
        let productName = `<div class="productName">${food.name}</div>`
        cartModalProduct.innerHTML = productName;

        let productPrice = `<div class="productPrice">${food.price}</div>`
        cartModalPrice.innerHTML = productPrice;

        let productQuantity = `<div class="productQuantity">${food.inCart}</div>`
        cartModalQuantity.innerHTML = productQuantity;

        let totalPrice = `<div class="totalPrice">${totalPriceValue}</div>`
        cartModalTotalPrice.innerHTML = totalPrice
    });
}
```

}

my full js code is here = https://jsfiddle.net/Birrellc/3w0shaom/

thanks

Comment: As you seem to suggest that your code works, but you want to have it better organised, your question would potentially be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But please check their info pages.

Comment: use revealing module pattern, which handles *cart* from fetching to rendering, or ditch vanilla and use vue or react.. a bunch of global functions is not the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of quick things:

1. Move data preparation to a different function.
2. Return false if no data to precess in order to avoid nested functions.
3. Use simplified variables and object properties.
4. Don't use a variable if you can pass expression directly.

   ```
   const getCartData = () => ({
       products: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("foodInCart")),
       priceValue: sessionStorage.getItem("totalPrice") || 0,
       product: document.querySelector('.product'),
       price: document.querySelector('.price'),
       quantity: document.querySelector('.quantity'),
       totalPrice: document.querySelector('.total-price')
   })


   function updateModal() {
       let cart = getCartData()
       if (cart.products == null) { return false }
       cart.product.innerHTML = '';
       Object.values(cart.products).map(food => {
           cart.product.innerHTML = `<div class="productName">${food.name}</div>`;
           cart.price.innerHTML = `<div class="productPrice">${food.price}</div>`;
           cart.quantity.innerHTML = `<div class="productQuantity">${food.inCart}</div>`;
           cart.price.innerHTML = `<div class="totalPrice">${cart.totalPrice}</div>`
       });
   }
   ```

I have forked your fiddle with changes https://jsfiddle.net/zhy5n8ga/